# Malformed Specrunner file - grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs

Tags: node.js, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I am using `grunt-contrib-jasmine` with `grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs` to generate the template. It was all working fine on Node v0.12.14, but when I upgraded to Node v4.5.0, my specrunner file output is malformed. It has chunks of JavaScript in the output as well as HTML. Example chunk:

```
function (obj) {
obj || (obj = {});
var __t, __p = '', __j = Array.prototype.join;
function print() { __p += __j.call(arguments, '') }
with (obj) {
__p += '<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  <meta charset="utf-8">\n  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>\n\n  ';
 css.forEach(function(style){ ;
__p += '\n  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' +
((__t = ( style )) == null ? '' : __t) +
'">\n  ';
 }) ;
__p += '\n\n  ';
 with (scripts) { ;
__p += '\n  ';
 [].concat(vendor).forEach(function(script){ ;
__p += '\n  <script src="' +
((__t = ( script )) == null ? '' : __t) +
'"></script>\n  ';
```

Here is the 'jasmine' section in my Gruntfile:

```
    jasmine: {
        test: {
            options:  {
                vendor: ["src/libs/jquery.js"],
                display: "short",
                summary: true,
                specs: ['test/test.js'],
                styles: ['src/css/main.css'],
                template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
                templateOptions: {
                    requireConfig: {
                        baseUrl: 'src/',
                        paths: {
                            "test": "../test",
                            "jquery-1.9": "jquery-1.9.1"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Has some 'templateOptions' for 'grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs' changed that I'm not aware of? Here are the versions I'm using:

```
grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs 0.2.3
grunt-contrib-requirejs 1.0.0
grunt-contrib-jasmine 1.0.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since updating to Grunt v1.0.1, the issue is with the package, `grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs`, which is no longer maintained. It should handle the template differently: `grunt.util._.template(source, context)` should be `grunt.util._.template(source)(context)`. Also, the Lodash version it uses collided with our version of Lodash.

There is a fork here which fixes these issues: https://github.com/radum/grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs/tree/7ca7ad28b1bbb7a940de7a01710f62c5b0eb6a65

However, this fork still uses the now deprecated `grunt.util._`, so it may need readdressing in future.